# How do I import xml data into a sql server database table in Windows form using c#?

Tags: asp.net

I wanted to display Xml data into the sql server database table.
First, I displayed the Xml data using the console application at run time, but now I want to store that XMl data into the database table.
How can I do this?

Himanshu Negi

Comment: Do you want to store the XML string or the values of elements and nodes within that string?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your XML is supposed to be a string (or it can easily be converted to).
So you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (your_col)
SELECT xml_str
```

I'm assuming you know how to connect to your db and run a `SqlCommand` after the connection is established...